# Purity of Frobenius on cohomology of a projective variety over $\mathbb F_q$ with isolated singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, weil-conjectures

Let $X_0$ be a projective variety of dimension $n>0$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ of characteristic $p$. Let $X$ denote its base change to an algebraic closure. Let $\ell$ be a prime number different from $p$. Assume that $X_0$ has isolated singularities. Is it true that the Frobenius action is pure on $\mathrm H^i(X,\overline{\mathbb Q_{\ell}})$ for $n+1 \leq i \leq 2n$? By purity, I mean that all the eigenvalues of the Frobenius have complex modulus $q^{i/2}$ under any choice of isomorphism $\overline{\mathbb Q_{\ell}} \simeq \mathbb C$.

This is the conclusion I reached by considering the intersection complex on $X$, but it sounds like it's too good to be true. However I wasn't able to come up with a counterexample. Thus I'd like to ask for your insights.

Comment: A generic hyperplane section of $X$ will be smooth, so you might be able to conclude by hyperplane Lefschetz.

Comment: Already Goresky-Macpherson's original paper shows that for a variety with isolated singularities, cohomology agrees with intersection cohomology above the middle degree. So this is also one approach to proving purity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [Piotr Achinger's suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455755/purity-of-frobenius-on-cohomology-of-a-projective-variety-over-mathbb-f-q-wit#comment1180003_455755), if we let $z$ be the inclusion of a smooth hyperplane $H$ and $j$ its affine open complement $U$, the distinguished triangle $z_* z^! \mathbb Q_\ell \to \mathbb Q_\ell \to j_* j^* \mathbb Q_\ell = j_* \mathbb Q_\ell$ (all functors derived) gives the long exact sequence $H^i ( H, z^! \mathbb Q_\ell) \to H^i (X, \mathbb Q_\ell) \to H^i ( U, \mathbb Q_\ell )$ and by Artin's affine theorem $H^i(U, \mathbb Q_\ell)=0$ for $i>n$ so  $H^i(H, z^! \mathbb Q_\ell) \to H^i(X, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ is surjective for $i>n$ but $H^i (H, z^! \mathbb Q_\ell) = H^i ( H, \mathbb Q_\ell[-2](-1))= H^{i-2} (H, \mathbb Q_\ell(-1))$ is pure of weight $i$ since $z$ is locally the inclusion of a smooth hyperplane section, so $ H^i(X, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ is pure of weight $i$ for $i>n$ also.

The fact that $z^! \mathbb Q_\ell = \mathbb Q_\ell[-2d](-d)$ for $z$ a closed immersion of a smooth variety of dimension $n-d$ into a smooth variety of dimension $n$ follows from the fact that for $s$ a smooth morphism of dimension $n$, $s^! K = K[2n](n)$ for any $K$ (not sure of the reference but it should be everywhere that discusses upper shrieks) which gives for $s$ the map from the $n$-dimensional variety to the poin

$$ \mathbb Q_\ell [2(n-d) ](n-d) = (s \circ z)^! \mathbb Q_\ell= z^! s^! \mathbb Q_\ell = z^! \mathbb Q_\ell[2n](n) $$ and shifting and Tate twisting both sides gives the conclusion. These two facts, about smooth immersions and closed immersions of smooth varieties, are the second two facts you should learn about upper shrieks after the adjointness.

Comment: Dear Will, thank you very much for expanding Piotr's idea. If you don't mind, I'd like to ask some questions to make sure that I understand well. Is the fact that $X$ has isolated singularities used to justify the existence of such a smooth hyperplane $H$? Besides, how is the affineness of the open complement $U$ automatic? Eventually, your computation seems to suggest that $z^! \mathbb Q_{\ell} \simeq \mathbb Q_{\ell}[-2](-1)$ in the derived category. How may one prove this? Essentially, all I know about the upper shriek in the $\ell$-adic context is its right adjointness to $i_! = i_*$.

Comment: @Suzet (1) Yes, a general hyperplane won't intersect the singularities, and then the usual argument showing a general hyperplane in a smooth variety is smooth applies. (2) The complement of any hyperplane in a projective variety is affine, almost by definition. (3) See edit.

Comment: One last thing to note is that even though $X$ is not smooth, the smooth hyperplane $z \colon H \hookrightarrow X$ is contained in a smooth open $v \colon V \hookrightarrow X$ (namely the complement of the finitely many singular points of $X$), so you can compute $z^! \mathbf Q_\ell$ as $(z')^! v^! \mathbf Q_\ell$, where $z' \colon H \hookrightarrow V$ is the closed immersion. Finally, $v^! \mathbf Q_\ell = v^* \mathbf Q_\ell = \mathbf Q_\ell$ since $v$ is étale (in fact, an open immersion).

Comment: Thank you very much again, Will and @R.vanDobbendeBruyn. It's all clear now!